# Android - make seekbar invisible but still functional

Tags: android, opacity, seekbar

I want to have the effect of a SeekBar but I don't want it to be visible. I want the user to slide their finger left and right over an image to decrease/increase opacity of an image. I have this working with a SeekBar, setting the alpha of the image as progress on the SeekBar changes. The challenge now is to hide the SeekBar. I just want the user to move their finger over the image back and forth and it change the opacity.

I have tried:

```
final SeekBar opacitySeekBar = (SeekBar) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.opacitySeekBar);
opacitySeekBar.setAlpha(0);
```

also:

```
opacitySeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it, 2 step process. So in the xml for the SeekBar, I added this line to make the progress bar invisible: 

    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"

And in the code, I added this line to make the thumb invisible:

    opacitySeekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);

Comment: You gave me a great idea and made my day. Thanks dude!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could have also just used View.GONE instead of View.INVISIBLE

Comment: I didn't try this, but View.GONE "doesn't take any space for layout purposes" so I'm not sure that would work. I still wanted it to be there, just not visible.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it, 2 step process. So in the xml for the SeekBar, I added this line to make the progress bar invisible:

```
android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
```

And in the code, I added this line to make the thumb invisible:

```
opacitySeekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: Need to point, that setting background and progress for seekbar like this

                    android:backgroundTint="#00ffffff"
                    android:progressTint="#00ffffff"

does not work on all devices; so use this answer code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SeekBar
        ...
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="@null"
        ... />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: I think the code is self explanatory: Just add these two lines to you SeekBar View. If you want to understand what these attributes do read the Android documentation.